# Swift read userInfo of remote notification

Tags: ios, json, swift, push-notification, userinfo

I implemented a function to open an AlertView when I receive a remote notification like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
        var notifiAlert = UIAlertView()
        var NotificationMessage : AnyObject? =  userInfo["alert"]
        notifiAlert.title = "TITLE"
        notifiAlert.message = NotificationMessage as? String
        notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        notifiAlert.show()
}
```

But NotificationMessage is always nil.

My json payload looks like this:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testmessage","badge":"1"}}
```

I am using Xcode 6, Swift and I am developing for iOS8.
I searched hours now, but didn't find any useful information.
The Notifications works perfectly.. and if I click it, the alertview opens.
My problem is, that I am not able to get the data out of userInfo.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The root level item of the `userInfo` dictionary is `"aps"`, not `"alert"`.

Try the following:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
           //Do stuff
        }
    } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

See [Push Notification Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Comment: How would this look in objective C++?

Comment: Its good that you've informed OP the root level item is aps and not alert in the userInfo dic .... but how does one find out the correct keys and dictionary structure that is within an iOS system sent notification userInfo dictionary. in swift 4 documentation i can see notification names all standardised within Notification.Name but i can't see any documentation saying ... this is the userInfo dictionary sent with a particular notification and here are the keys..?

Comment: is it possible to add more parameters in aps?

Answer (score 17):

#### Swift 5

```swift
struct Push: Decodable {
    let aps: APS
    
    struct APS: Decodable {
        let alert: Alert
        
        struct Alert: Decodable {
            let title: String
            let body: String
        }
    }
    
    init(decoding userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo, options: .prettyPrinted)
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Push.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
guard let push = try? Push(decoding: userInfo) else { return }
let alert = UIAlertController(title: push.aps.alert.title, message: push.aps.alert.body, preferredStyle: .alert)
```

Answer (score 11):

Method (Swift 4):

```
func extractUserInfo(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> (title: String, body: String) {
    var info = (title: "", body: "")
    guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] else { return info }
    guard let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: Any] else { return info }
    let title = alert["title"] as? String ?? ""
    let body = alert["body"] as? String ?? ""
    info = (title: title, body: body)
    return info
}
```

Usage:

```
let info = self.extractUserInfo(userInfo: userInfo)
print(info.title)
print(info.body)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, when I send the message from [Accengage](https://mobilecrm.accengage.com), the following code works -

```
private func extractMessage(fromPushNotificationUserInfo userInfo:[NSObject: AnyObject]) -> String? {
    var message: String?
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alertMessage = alert["body"] as? String {
                message = alertMessage              
            }
        }
    }
    return message
}
```

The only difference from Craing Stanford's answer is the `key` I used to extract message from `alert` instance which is `body` which is different. See below for more clearification -

```
if let alertMessage = alert["message"] as? NSString
```

vs

```
if let alertMessage = alert["body"] as? String
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my version for objC

```
if (userInfo[@"aps"]){
    NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@"aps"];
    if (aps[@"alert"]){
        NSObject *alert = aps[@"alert"];
        if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
            NSDictionary *alertDict = aps[@"alert"];
            if (alertDict[@"message"]){
                NSString *message = alertDict[@"message"];
            }
        }
        else if (aps[@"alert"]){
            NSString *alert = aps[@"alert"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Alert should be showing while the app is in active state. So check the state is active or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .active {
      if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alertMessage = aps["alert"] as? String {
          let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
          let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
          alert.addAction(action)
          self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
  }
```

> From this if a user need message then he can get alert message.

Answer (score 0):

I use APNs Provider and json payload as below

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
      "title" : "I am title",
      "body" : "message body."
    },
  "sound" : "default",
  "badge" : 1
  }
}
```

Due to the provider originates it as a JSON-defined dictionary that iOS converts to an `NSDictionary` object, without subscript like `Dictionary`, but can use `value(forKey:)`

Reference from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

This's my way for Swift 4

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    guard application.applicationState == .active else { return }
    guard let alertDict = ((userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "alert")) as? NSDictionary,
        let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
        let body = alertDict["body"] as? String
        else { return }
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: body, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAct = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAct)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
}
```