# Can I check push notifications using Xcode's UI test?

Tags: push-notification, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

We have some apps where we need to check push notifications in regular interval. Can we check push notifications via Xcode UI test?

Comment: I made a few edits to my answer, please take a look

Answer (score -3):

Disclaimer: I haven't done this...

You can't generate a token...so I *guess* the answer would be No! What can do is a mock your notificationManager with stub data.

With the stub data you test:

1. Does your callback function download what want it to?
2. Or maybe assuming you have alerts when app is in foreground:  are you
   showing an alert?

Otherwise if you're purely up to testing to see if the app throws the [callback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) when it receives a notification then you're testing the OS and that's wrong. You should only test your own code.

By testing your notificationManager I roughly mean something like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        NotificationManager.shared.handle(userInfo)
}
```

Your NotificationManager class

```
func handleAPNSMessage(_ message:[AnyHashable: Any]) {

if let aps = message["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
           //Do stuff
        }
    } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
        //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596529/5175709)</sub>

Now what you do is, you mock calling `handleAPNSMessage` with a JSON object that looks same as the one your server would send you,

If you want to go crazy and really duplicate the remote notifications then you could use your own stub data and create local notifications... and see if the app works as you expect...

**EDIT:**

Make sure you see [How can I test Apple Push Notification Service without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865509/5175709)

Comment: I can trigger push notification from a tool which we developed. Thats not a problem. I'm asking whether can I get elements and its identifiers via XCTestCase from push notifications?

Comment: @Confused not sure what you mean by 'elements' and 'identifiers'. I mean you're sending a object through payload right? You can get all its keys/values —assuming you can trigger it

Comment: I asked this question about XCTest UI testing, not with notification related mechanism.

Comment: @Confused Did you try to use the Xcode's record feature?

Comment: @Confused, how did you trigger the push notifications with uitests?

Comment: @Confused see my edit. My previous answer wasn't clear at all. Sorry