# access value for dictionary key in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am having a problem with accessing the value of the key alert in [AnyHashable("aps")]. I am trying to store the notification alert into a string so I can do further actions, but I was not able to access the alert value. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

I am new to swift and trying to get my hands dirty through building my own app. I appreciate your help guys!

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler([.sound, .alert])
}
```

actual output:

```
[
    AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1559231429586204%16146ddd16146ddd,
    AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 1559231429,
    AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert = "BBQ event on 6/15";
        sound = enabled;
    },
    AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1,
    AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0,
    AnyHashable("gcm.notification.sound2"): enabled,
    AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1,
    AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 5464147931275974726
]
```

expected output:

```
"BBQ event on 6/15"
```

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596295/swift-read-userinfo-of-remote-notification

Comment: @ColeJames thank you that what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first fetch value of `aps` as `Dictionary` of type `[AnyHashable:Any]`. Then get the value of `alert` from `apsDict`, i.e.

```
if let apsDict = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable:Any] {
    if let alert = apsDict["alert"] {
        print("Alert: \(alert)")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you thats what I was looking to do! it worked like a charm!

Comment: Done. Sorry I do not use stack overflow all the time :)  Happy Coding